# Removing the protection of Windows for serial communication

Tags: windows, serial

I am running an Arduino on the USB serial port. I am trying to access the data from the serial port and print it on the python output terminal. However, when I get this error message from python:

```
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in 
open
raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, 
ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'com3': PermissionError(13, 
'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

I know this is the Windows trying to protect me but I need to turn it off for some time. How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to close down the serial monitor on your Arduino since it counts as a serial monitor which means that the COM3 port is busy transfering data there.